# Login page edit

Tags: iis

I want to edit the login page of an application,  provided by a third party vendor which is installed on a windows server 2012. I want to change the following :

1.login page tab name 
2. Change the login page image

I tried going through the web.config file but I could not understand much. I also tried to replace the image with some changes but it did not affect the login page.

How can I zero down to the path and the HTML/CSS files to make this changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way to change the tab name and tab image is as follow.

1. Open login page in IE, right click and select properties option. In properties, you will be able to see the address URL, something like e.g. **abc.com/login/login.html**. Go to the directory of application in windows server, and navigate to folder named **Login** and inside there will be a login.html file. Open the file and search for the current tab name. You will possibly find it inside title tags. e.g. If the login page tab name is **Login**, then you will find it enclosed inside title tags like `<title>Login</title>`. Update that name inside title tags to your required value and refresh the page in browser. you will see the updated tab name.
2. In order to update the tab image, you will find URL of login tab image enclosed in `<link href="URL OF THE LOGIN TAB IMAGE"`, change the URL with the URL of the different image you want to show. Once done refresh the page in browser and you will see the updated image in tab.

I do hope it helps you. There are other ways to inspect the login page using browser developer tools (by pressing F12 key) and using inspect option, but that method is more inclined for developers and I am not entirely sure that you are developer. If you are then I hope this will be to of some assistance in figuring out the change you want to apply.

Comment: hey i did all you have mentioned ..but the funny thing is page link does not end with .html but with serverip/login

Comment: @ty139 - In your application folder, do you see any sub directory named login? you need to search for that login web page file that is being pulled up on browser. Once that file is found open it and follow the steps I've mentioned in answer. Its not necessary that file will end with .html. It can also end with .aspx or .cshtml etc.